# Set directory for fixture_file_upload in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

When using `fixture_file_upload`, the files are being uploaded to `public/tmp` as expected. However, these files are being created in a factory (`factory_girl`), and so my `public/tmp` is full of files uploaded during tests.

What is the recommended way to clear those files, or delete files after object is destroyed during testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use RSpec you can define a block which run before or after the suite.
I prefere to delete the files before. This will leave the files after the tests, so I can inspect the temp-files; but it clears old files before the test, so I have a clean path each time I run the tests.

in `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ......
  config.before(:all) do
    if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
      FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir["#{pstore_path}/[^.]*"])
    end
  end
```

`pstore_path` is another method in my spec_helper-file. You may change the line `FileUtils.rm_rf....` to remove only the files you want to delete instead of an entire directory as shown in this example.

You can combine before and after filter to record the files already exists before the tests and then remove any files created during the test in an `config.after` block.